# Downsampling vs. ADC with lower Sample-Rate

Tags: sampling, frequency, downsampling, analog-to-digital

I would like to know in general where the advantages and disadvantages are:

1. Downsampling of a high sampled continuous analog signal in FPGA or µC and
2. Direct use of a lower sampling rate, i.e. using an analog to digital converter with a lower sampling rate ?
   Are there any differences or does it have the same effect ?
   Because almost every DSP-System i see uses a way Oversampling followed by Decimation (Downsampling + AAF-Filter) instead of adequate Sampling Rate without Decimation.

Greetings

Comment: uhm, i still dunno what exactly is the question.  is it about the relative merits of two different ways of doing sample-rate-conversion?  perhaps asynchronous sample-rate-conversion (ASRC)?  one is the analog way with an D/A, analog LPF, and A/D at the new rate.  the other is purely digital.  is this what the question is about?

Comment: Hi, the question is about the advantages and disadvantages between sampling a signal either at the desired sampling rate (using an ADC with exactly this sampling rate), or first a significant oversampling and then reaching the desired sampling rate by downsampling. - Because almost every DSP-System i see uses a way Oversampling followed by Decimation (Downsampling + AAF-Filter) instead of adequate Sampling Rate without Decimation.

Comment: so is the question about what is called *"Sigma-Delta"* conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many advantages, but the most obvious to me

Advantage 1 :

Oversampling followed by decimation allows you use to simpler and smaller anti-aliasing filters. These filters cost less, take up less space on a PCboard, draw less power, etc.

Advantage 2 :

In multi-channel applications, the tolerance and variation of the analog components of your anti-aliasing filters can cause skew between the channels. The cut-off frequency is determined by the value of the resistors and capacitors. While it's easy to get resistor with a ± 0.1% tolerance, it is much harder to get capacitors with a ± 0.1% tolerance. A ballpark estimate yields a ± 1% bandwidth tolerance for an order-1 filter, 2% for an order-2 filter, etc.

Oversampling followed by decimation will make the overall bandwidth more dependant on the digital anti-aliasing filter (in the decimation process) and less on the analog anti-aliasing filter. If your application requires a 0.1 % bandwidth tolerance between multiple channels, oversampling is the way to go.

Disadvantage :

You need faster ADCs and faster digital electronics (CPU, or FPGA). It costs more and usually draws more power.

Answer (score 2):

With downsampling you have complete control over the process and it comes down to what compromise of processing complexity, delay, aliasing and loss of passband you can accept.

With a lower rate A/D you are pretty much at the mercy of someone elses spectral trade-offs and in addition you get the quantization/noise of one analog pass.

-k

Comment: I disagree with your second paragraph -- it assumes that you don't get any say in the analog circuitry before the lower-rate ADC.  In theory you *could* do any amount of filtering in analog-land before ADC-ing.  It's just that in many practical problems, it's easier to sample fast and do filtering in digital-land, then decimate.

Comment: True. But commercial AD and DA (at least for audio) tends to employ multi rate topologies, and might offer a choice between a couple preset filter characteristics. While you could, in principle, do additional purely analog filtering in between them, I dont think that is practical for the kind of filter orders one typically are interested in here. My point about noise/quantization still stands.

Answer (score 2):

And additional consideration not mentioned that comes up in radio design is in the decision to use quadrature sampling of a baseband signal (as in "Zero-IF receivers") over a "Digital-IF" receiver that is achievable when the signal can be sampled at a much higher rate as a real signal. The Digital IF signal avoids the quadrature imbalance errors that would be introduced in the analog at both the local oscillators and notably in the I and Q signal paths after the down-conversion from analog RF or IF takes place. This latter effect is much more challenging to compensate for given its variation over frequency.